# "Disk not ejected correctly" msg from 2016 MacBook laptop

Tags: external-disk

I sometimes use the laptop periodically throughout day without unplugging it or the external drives.  However, if it puts itself to sleep as a result of a period of inactivity, when I reawaken it, I get the message "Disk not ejected correctly"    How can I get rid of this message as I have not removed the disks at all, the data is not corrupted, and I have not told the computer to go to sleep!

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, to completely get rid of the message, you can go to System Preferences -> Energy Saver and uncheck the box that says "Put hard disks to sleep when possible". That will eliminate the message, but it also means that your computer will use more energy and that the hard drives will be on and spinning constantly.

If this doesn't work, let me know. (Disclaimer: It's possible this won't work; I can't remember if "Put hard disks to sleep when possible" works only for internal drives or also for external ones.)

Comment: Hi NoahL,  No this didn't work....... I have no moving disk in the computer which is a 2015 MacBook with a single USB-C port.   The disks that are continually producing the 'not ejected properly' message are attached via a 4-socket hub.   One is the Time Machine backup and the other is one I use for extra day to day storage and my photos.  The message appears even if I have not closed the computer, but the screen saver has elected to put it to sleep due to inactivity.  I have never (yet) last any data as the disks have not actually been removed - they are still plugged in!